# Logging into Microsoft account using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use selenium to log into my Microsoft account. The code below causes the site to return an error message saying something went wrong during login.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://login.live.com')

#locating email field and entering my email
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("i0116")
elem.send_keys("myEmailAddress")

#locating password field and entering my password
elem2 = browser.find_element_by_id("i0118")
elem2.send_keys("myPassword")


elem.submit()
```

The password I am entering is definitely correct. Could it be that Microsoft simply does not want remote controlled browsing sessions to attempt login?

Answer (score 16):

I think you need to be waiting, as the fields don't show immediately. The following worked for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

EMAILFIELD = (By.ID, "i0116")
PASSWORDFIELD = (By.ID, "i0118")
NEXTBUTTON = (By.ID, "idSIButton9")

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://login.live.com')

# wait for email field and enter email
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(EMAILFIELD)).send_keys("myEmailAddress")

# Click Next
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

# wait for password field and enter password
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PASSWORDFIELD)).send_keys("myPassword")

# Click Login - same id?
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()
```

Comment: I was actually able to accomplish this by using the time.sleep() function. But this is likely a better solution.

Comment: Definitely. Use sleep sparingly, it can have unpredictable outcomes.

Comment: Using selenium how would you add two-factor authentication support? The "Verify your identity" page is a form-group where you need to choose between mediums for the two-factor and the choices are presented in a form-group of tables?

Comment: I had this exact same problem this morning and a quickly learned for myself using a `Thread.Sleep(3000);` allows the system to have a moment to catch up, then login is smooth. So I agree, this answer is a better solution and will apply this to my code when I’m back in the office today.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, it waits a second until the home button or any other element I need appears, so I don't depend on a static timeout.

```
driver.get("https://login.live.com")
valcon = True
while (valcon):
    try:
        if (driver.find_element(By.ID, 'idSIButton9') is None):
            time.sleep(1)
            valcon = True
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            valcon = False
    except:
        valcon = True

u = "usuario@hotmail.com"
usu = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'i0116')
usu.clear()
usu.send_keys(u)
ing = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'idSIButton9')
ing.click()
```

Answer (score -1):

use.. this.. work for me..better to wait until reach on desired URL

wait.until((Function) ExpectedConditions.urlContains("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"));

```
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
        WebElement confirmationButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"idSIButton9\"]"));

        if (confirmationButton.isEnabled())
        {
            confirmationButton.click();
        }
```